# Connect to SignalR hub in Unity3d (For Hololens)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, signalr, hololens

Is it possible to connect to a SignalR server using Unity?

I'm making a Hololens application(so I build to windows store app) that need to communicate with a SignalR hub to post information. This server is already made and I have only the URI, hub name and the hub interface endpoints.

Current issues:

SignalR framework requires .net 4.5 which Unity's current mono version doesn't work with. Even if I manage to get the reference in, Unity won't be able to build it to a windows store app as Unity reverts the solutions version to 3.5 unity subset which doesn't include async functionality that is introduced in .net 4.0.

https://github.com/robink-teleopti/SignalR simply exploded with errors in unity.

https://github.com/jenyayel/SignalR.Client.20 lacks a bunch of definitions in Thread, Stream, LongLength, HTTPWebRequest.

Nivot.SignalR.Client.Net35 uses async functionality that Unity doesn't understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect from the UW application to connect to signalR and use a bridge to communicate with the Unity application:

(App/Web-server) bridge:

```
internal class UnityBridge
{
    private static UnityBridge _instance;

    private UnityBridge()
    {
        SelectHandler.SelectedHandler = CallExternal;
    }

    public static UnityBridge Create()
    {
        return _instance ?? (_instance = new UnityBridge());
    }

    private void CallExternal(string nameTag)
    {
        var conn = new HubConnection("http://xxx.azurewebsites.net");
        var proxy = conn.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        conn.Start().Wait();
        proxy.Invoke("Send", new EngineerAction {ExecutedAction = nameTag});
    }
}
```

(App/Web-server) In your `App.cs`

```
    private AppCallbacks m_AppCallbacks;
    private UnityBridge _unityBridge;

    public App()
    {
        m_AppCallbacks = new AppCallbacks();

        // Allow clients of this class to append their own callbacks.
        AddAppCallbacks(m_AppCallbacks);
    }

    virtual protected void AddAppCallbacks(AppCallbacks appCallbacks)
    {
        _unityBridge = UnityBridge.Create();

    }
```

(Unity game-client/server) And in your unity scripts:

```
public class SelectHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void SelectedHandlerDelegate(string nameTag);
    public static SelectedHandlerDelegate SelectedHandler;
    ....

        //call 
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(() => SelectedHandler("teststring"), false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Peter! This sounds like a great idea although it is way over my head, but I'll try implement it into my solution to see if it works.

Comment: @Piees did you get it to work? Interested in SignalR for the Hololens too.

Comment: I didn't and the module has been postponed, I'll update if I get the module active and resolve it.